# Unable to authenticate via GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-authentication

The app is supposed to authenticate the user on the first launch (or on the future launches if the first try has failed). Authentication logic is encapsulated in the `AsyncTask` and is implemented in the following method (user account and scope are valid):

```
private String fetchToken() throws IOException {
    try {
        return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mParentActivity, mUserEmail, mScope);
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userRecoverableException) {
        if (!secondTry) {
            secondTry = true;
            mParentActivity.handleException(userRecoverableException);
        }
    } catch (GoogleAuthException fatalException) {
        fatalException.printStackTrace();
        mParentActivity.handleException(fatalException);
    }
    return null;
}
```

`handleException` method:

```
public void handleException(final Exception e) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (e instanceof GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException) {
                int statusCode = ((GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException) e).getConnectionStatusCode();
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(statusCode, MainActivity.this,
                        REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
                dialog.show();
            } else if (e instanceof UserRecoverableAuthException) {
                Intent intent = ((UserRecoverableAuthException) e).getIntent();
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_RECOVER_FROM_AUTH_ERROR);
            } else if (e instanceof GoogleAuthException) {
                showToast("Fatal error during authentication");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Testing this code on different devices revealed that there is no strict pattern to detect the cause of the error. The symptoms are:

- multiple *signing in* activities appear on top of each other and none of them succeed:
  [image: signing in]
- multiple `UserRecoverableAuthException`s are thrown even if I set `secondTry` flag to prevent it;

Also, following exceptions are spotted in the LogCat:

```
11-10 13:50:30.610: D/GLSActivity(4223): Starting LoginActivityTask for user: qwerty@gmail.com...
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.LatencyTracker
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.LatencyTracker
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3761)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:4977)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3173)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3129)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:157)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2125)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/auth/firstparty/shared/LatencyTracker
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     ... 18 more
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didnt find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.LatencyTracker" on path: .
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-10 13:50:30.615: E/Parcel(2345):     ... 18 more

...

11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.AppDescription
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.AppDescription
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3761)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:4977)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3391)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:254)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:3283)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:258)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2125)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/android/gms/auth/firstparty/shared/AppDescription
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     ... 19 more
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didnt find class "com.google.android.gms.auth.firstparty.shared.AppDescription" on path: .
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-10 13:50:30.625: E/Parcel(2345):     ... 19 more
```

Does anyone have any suggestions what causes this issue?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: I didn't investigate this problem for a while. If I find a solution I'll post it.

Comment: I'm using GoogleApiClient which is basically the same flow and I keep getting requests to authenticate off line over and over again. I believe we are seeing the same problem. I assume there's still no solution?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I am running into the same issue too